# Ggplot2 legend ignores point colors in faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the following dataset (see below) using ggplot2. The code I am using is:

```
ggplot(test,mapping=aes(x=XValue,y=YValue,fill=PM,shape=KL))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(FT="red",PP="black"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,24))+
  facet_wrap(~KL)
```

This produces the folowing plot, which is OK *except* for the legend. Here the categories "FT" and "PP" should be red and black in the legend, too - but both of them are depicted in black. The split in circles and triangles is correct though. How can I adjust the legend so that the colors match the actual figure?

[image: Example_plot]

The data:

```
test<-structure(list(XValue = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("0", "1", "3", "4", 
"6", "8", "12", "24", "20"), class = "factor"), PM = c("FT", 
"FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", 
"FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", 
"FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "FT", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP"), KL = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("K1", "K2"), class = "factor"), 
    YValue = c(3.1659596427119, 3.1219098873624, 3.14672408788822, 
    0.986728824528058, 0.970927123484596, 0.851697057001025, 
    6.18813529232518, 6.16250945274165, 6.10036718879546, 2.04585765804258, 
    2.01010012388677, 1.98540967919073, 1.96831567755578, 4.54473669569724, 
    4.51674283471371, 4.57968928259083, 2.28260907382727, 2.33546233929094, 
    2.21330224364371, 2.23912504349744, 2.02414383523147, 2.07670244369616, 
    2.05701137806227, 2.18747377389903, 2.10975270957976, 2.11196078067211, 
    2.08020174459454, 1.90555716664908, 1.94338771258761, 1.90454928900316, 
    2.34332445212985, 2.2801434791366, 2.29583570117039, 1.79373583477998, 
    1.7921731037672, 1.80092325112501, 1.57072891453888, 1.53583763615075, 
    1.53852302844113, 1.50077935623981, 2.32516428610227, 2.26667663882382, 
    2.2571443123735, 1.72927075549124, 1.68745803873649, 1.67100312911936, 
    1.65473272587735, 2.53309570110105, 2.48119569321443, 2.49075439101024, 
    1.679672753252, 1.56814675032307, 1.6057015152944, 1.61552779426337, 
    2.63579787756314, 2.60255488643132, 2.62594327021028, 1.46141497013179, 
    1.4200887994802, 1.41179528904952, 3.22314580592308, 3.21369507872032, 
    3.22968843307558, 1.6003688022661, 1.5676859833415, 1.52704069853153, 
    1.52699091649978, 4.11433428998552, 4.08672056128983, 4.03041446478611, 
    1.47582738219854, 1.55797514144288, 1.5787805691956, 1.60176966345038, 
    1.58144396087639, 1.49501753126975, 1.50288648673506, 1.49649216185024, 
    1.50002421213479)), row.names = c(NA, -79L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the default shape for points doesn't have a fill colour.  If you use `override.aes` as below you can set the `shape` for the legend points to 21 which can be filled, so your legend works as expected:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test,mapping=aes(x=XValue,y=YValue,fill=PM,shape=KL))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(FT="red",PP="black") )+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21 ) ))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,24))+
  facet_wrap(~KL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly what I was searching for and you even explained why it didn't work in the first place for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that standard point shape legend displays standard fill color (background of legend box) and standard fill legend displays standard shape (circle). Each option of `KL` (`K1` and `K2`) has both red and black fills (can be black or red) and each option of `PM` (`FT` and `PP`) has both shapes (can be triangular of circular). In other words there is no specific shape to fill red or black and there is no specific fill to draw triangle and circle.

So their fills are dropped to standard. You can combine these two legends in one. You can use `interaction()` for this:

```
ggplot(test,mapping=aes(x=XValue,
                        y=YValue,
                        fill=interaction(PM, KL), 
                        shape=interaction(PM, KL)
                        )
       )+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(FT.K1="red", FT.K2="red",PP.K1="black",PP.K2="black"), name = "Legend")+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(FT.K1=21, FT.K2=24,PP.K1=21,PP.K2=24), name = "Legend")+
  facet_wrap(~KL)
```

[image]

Comment: This is also a neat trick that I did not know about. Thank you for sharing - however I prefered the original "separated" legend. Still- also your answer solves my problem!